# Exact significance, of menthological settings (imagery, symbolism, plans, but where is the role of constructs for obtaining divergence)?

Tags: terminology

What is a menthological setting?

Is it something, that lets your mind, interleave, expand, (and diverge!), along the lines, of a mental setting?

Thanks.

(For example:

[example menthological construct](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/112800/41481)

).

Thanks.

Comment: What is "menthological"?

Answer (score 1):

The role of constructs? Well, imagine this -

Little Timmy was playing his favorite video game, an adventure game where the hero has to travel through different lands and solve puzzles to save the kingdom. As Timmy was playing, he started thinking about how he could create his own game world and story.

Timmy began using his knowledge of the game mechanics and rules as conceptual constructs to spark new divergent thinking. The "hero's journey" structure became a construct that allowed him to imagine new characters, settings and plot elements that deviated from the original game. The fantasy genre became a conceptual space for him to explore imaginative new worlds filled with magic and mystical creatures.

The construct of "traveling through portals" inspired Timmy to envision adventures across distant lands and dimensions. The puzzle-solving construct provided a framework for devising new intriguing brain teasers. And the metaphor of "gathering ingredients for potions" opened up possibilities for crafting and collecting new items.

With these conceptual constructs as creative launch pads, Timmy diverged from the original gameplay and design. He imagined bold new characters like Sir Robot the Brave. He conceived magical lands in the sky reached by giant eagles. And he came up with innovative potion combinations that could turn you tiny or give you super strength.